# If $q=2^m+1$ for $m\geq 2$ is a prime, then $3^{\frac{q-1}{2}}\equiv -1\pmod q$

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory

I want to prove the statement in the title:

If $q=2^m+1$ for $m\geq 2$ is a prime, then $3^{\frac{q-1}{2}}\equiv -1\pmod q$.

I tried to suppose the negation, i.e. that $3^{\frac{q-1}{2}}\equiv 1\pmod q$, but I wasnt able to get something useful

Comment: That isnot the logical negation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a classical setting for Legendre symbols. We have
$$
3^{(q-1)/2} \equiv \left( \frac{3}{q} \right) \pmod{q}
$$
and by quadratic reciprocity, we also have
$$
\left( \frac{3}{q} \right) \left( \frac{q}{3} \right) = (-1)^{(q-1)/2} = 1.
$$
Note that as $q > 3$ is a prime, it follows that $q \equiv (-1)^m + 1 \equiv 2 \pmod{3}$. Therefore $q$ is not a residue mod $3$, and so
$$
\left( \frac{3}{q} \right) = -1,
$$
as required.